# How to make text rotate inside a div upon page refresh without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div :

```
  <div>This text rotates upon page refresh</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to make the text rotate inside the div upon page refresh; however, I don't want use any sort of jquery plug in to do achieve it.

If i have the following jQuery code:

```
 jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
     $(div).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
             '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
             '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
             'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
     return $(this);
  };
```

How can I specify inside the jquery that it is the text I want to rotate and not the div. I am trying to accomplish this without the use of tags.

Comment: Use a CSS3 animation?

Comment: Yes.  Use a CSS3 animation.  Tags are containers of information/objects, in order to do something to them, they are the reference point for Javascript.

Comment: Check [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) if you don'y want a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a bit of javascript, but here is a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/aLk8vfto/2/

And the js code:

```
(function() {
  document.getElementById('info').className += 'rotate';
})();
```

css:

```
div
{
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;

  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;

  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 50px;
}
.rotate
{
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```